# Application level feature set

Tags: symfony, behat

I moved my feature set to the application level.  In order to do that, I had to add the context.class parameter to my behat.yml file.  The reason I moved them to the application level is that I would like to be able to run all of my features from one place, but have my FeatureContext class files either at application level or in each class's appropriate bundle.  Is there a way to supply an array for context.class so that the feature will automatically look in multiple FeatureContext class files in multiple bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such parameter (yet). Things will gonna change in Behat 3.0.

For now, any class which can be autoloaded, can be used with Behat. You only need to configure a main context class in behat.yml. It's usually a FeatureContext class.

In your FeatureContext you can include additional contexts as [subcontexts](http://docs.behat.org/guides/4.context.html#using-subcontexts). Those subcontexts can be placed wherever you want.

However, I think it's good to stick to one approach. I mean, if you prefer to have all the feature files in one folder, do the same with your context files.